# Array to string convention problem when downloading excel file in laravel

Tags: laravel-6, maatwebsite-excel

HomeController :

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('personals')
            ->leftjoin('companies','personals.id','companies.id')
            ->get();
        return view('frontend/dashboard')->with(['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

This controller view dashboard has downlaod button.

dasboard view :

```
<form action="{{url('export')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">DownloadFile</button>
</form>
```

After clicking button it is going to following route :

```
Route::post('export', 'Excel\ExcelController@export');
```

Now the Controller :

```
public function export()
    {
        return Excel::download(new ExcelExport, 'excel.xlsx');

    }
```

Here ExcelExport is the model . So the model is given below :

```
public function collection()
    {
        $data = Personal::leftjoin('companies','personals.employeeId','=','companies.id')->first();
        return $data ;
    }
```

Expected result will after clicking on the download button it will download excel file.

But here show a error exception : Array to string convention.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you using maatwebsite/excel package ? i Think problem in maatwebsite package version for laravel 6

return Excel::download(new **ExcelExport**, 'excel.xlsx');

Here ExcelExport is Model. please check model data.

Follow this url [maatwebsite link](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/import-and-export-csv-file-in-laravel-58example.html) [laravel excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html)

Comment: ```"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"
    },

Comment: please run composer update command and php artisan config:cache

Comment: please downgrade maatwebsite/excel :2.1.0 then run composer dump-autoload

Comment: just open composer.json file and write maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1.0" in maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1" then run composer dump-autoload

Comment: I follow your instruction but same problem.